# php Pages not loading with php enabled

Tags: php, apache-2.4, ubuntu-16.04, php7

I have enabled php7.1 on my website as shown [here](http://multicrew.co.uk/info.php) but no php pages seem to load on my website, they just all come up as default code. I have tried enabling php5.6 and disabling 7.1 but that does not change anything. I am very confused why it doesnt work.

I am on apache2.4 and ubuntu 16.04

This is what I see in my apache error.log file

```
[Fri Feb 10 11:14:46.817334 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3144] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Feb 10 11:14:47.725712 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3464] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) PHP/7.1.1-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Feb 10 11:14:47.725854 2017] [core:notice] [pid 3464] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

And when I run

```
apache2 -e debug
```

I get this

```
[Fri Feb 10 11:16:32.582974 2017] [core:warn] [pid 3511] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Fri Feb 10 11:16:32.583330 2017] [core:warn] [pid 3511] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Fri Feb 10 11:16:32.583403 2017] [core:warn] [pid 3511] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
AH00526: Syntax error on line 74 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
Invalid Mutex directory in argument file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}
```

Comment: Do you have mod_php enabled or are you using php-fpm?

Comment: Um, not sure, how can I find out?

Comment: Try "sudo a2enmod php5" or "sudo a2enmod php7.0" depending on which version you have now..

Comment: Also check the output of this: "apachectl -V | grep MPM", if it is prefork, you can use mod_php, otherwise you need to use php-fpm.

Comment: It says prefork so I guess I can use mod_php

Comment: Yes, then you need to check that you have PHP installed and mod_php enabled. After enabling the module, restart apache "apachectl restart".

Comment: Where do I enable mod_php? Sorry

Comment: With that a2enmod <module_name> command

Comment: I thought so but it says it doesn't exist

Comment: What does this output for you "ls /etc/apache2/mods-available/ | grep -i php"?

Comment: `php5.6.conf
php5.6.load
php7.0.conf
php7.0.load
php7.1.conf
php7.1.load`

Comment: Ok.. the selected version only should be found as a symbolic link in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled.

Comment: Now that i checked that link which you provided, it seems that your php is ok.

Comment: That's what I am confused about. None of my php pages seem to load properly

Comment: That PHP page seemed to load properly, which ones arent loading? You should check apache error_log for error messages regarding those pages.

Comment: That's what also confuses me, there is nothing in the logs about it

Comment: And for example if I go on my forum page or my phpldapadmin dont seem to load properly

Comment: With this amount of information it is impossible to help you. You need to enble logging for those pages and get some logs here etc.

Comment: I seem to think I have enabled logging for the pages but I dont think its seeming to get logged :/

Comment: @HarryCameron: Please don't add this kind of information as a comment, it's useless and unreadable. Use the `edit` button, add it to the post and use the formatting tools to make it legible.

Comment: There we go, its updated